# Microsoft CRM Java

Tags: java, crm, live, microsoft-dynamics

Hi I'm trying to connect to crm online with my microsoft 365 login using java. I use the sample code given in java2crmcrud in crm sdk. I have replaced the myliveid@hotmail.com, mypassword and mycrmonlineinstance with the 365 credentials but the server responds as

Applies To:urn:crmemea:dynamics.com
Policy:MBI_FED_SSL
Issue Uri:https://login.live.com/extSTS.srf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault"><S:Body><S:Fault><S:Code><S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value><S:Subcode><S:Value>wst:FailedAuthentication</S:Value></S:Subcode></S:Code><S:Reason><S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Authentication Failure</S:Text></S:Reason><S:Detail><psf:error><psf:value>0x80048821</psf:value><psf:internalerror><psf:code>0x80041012</psf:code><psf:text>The entered and stored passwords do not match.&#x000D;&#x000A;</psf:text></psf:internalerror></psf:error></S:Detail></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java2crmpack.LiveIDManager.getValueFromXML(LiveIDManager.java:257)
    at java2crmpack.LiveIDManager.authenticateWithLiveID(LiveIDManager.java:183)
    at java2crmpack.Main.main(Main.java:85)
```

do I need to change or add anything. I guess the 365 accounts authentication are not same as live login authentication in crm. any help will b appreciated thank you.

Comment: i too faced the same issue. i just followed all the steps mentioned in URL "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx" while doing so i just missed Two points, based on our geographic location you have to give the crm as mentioned in point 2 and 3 under generate classes title and after that change while editing the main.java sample file in the OrganizationUniqueName it should be unique without space. that wil work i hope.